# How is a quadtree stored in a file?

Tags: data-structures, graphics

I'm trying to understand how a 2d or 3d map would be saved, and I'm trying to figure out quad trees. So like is each node represented by characters in a file and inside of that is the next one?

What exactly would the file look like, if its just a bunch of characters? Does the order of in which they are in the file signify nodes and child nodes?

Sorry if its unclear or doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: example `[0.3.3.0.1.2.2.1.0.3][36][x,y,w,h,data]`

Comment: It can be stored however you want to store it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How the data is stored is depends on the database or file type you're using for persistent data. What matters more is how the data is logically structured and that you can serialize/deserialize between your persistent storage and your structures in memory. You might want to read [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7952/how-to-choose-how-to-store-data) on gamedev stackexchange for more info on particular ways of storing game information.

Answer (score 1):

As with any recursively composite structure, the easiest way, in my opinion, is using recursion. For instance, you can pre-order-traverse the tree, storing each node in each step (you'd append the node at the end of the file). If the node has a fixed size (i.e., a fixed amount of properties with a fixed size each), it's pretty straightforward (remember the number of children is one of such properties!) If the size of a node can vary (e.g., one of the properties is an array), you should use a mechanism to know where each property ends (one recurrent solution is saving the property size before the property value, as well as any block or node's size).

However, if you need a more complex approach (like paging, or randomly access a certain node in the file directly) you'll need a more complex approach to saving/loading the quadtree/octree/whatever-tree. And there's just no silver bullet for that. You'll have to tailor a solution for your particular needs.